How to control the width of the DropdownMenuItem in DropdownButtonFormField in Flutter?
I spent a lot of time trying to fix the size of the expanded area (when you open the DropdownButtonFormField), but it always takes the full width of the screen



1
2









My code is:
DropdownButtonFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(RADIUS),
      ),
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
    ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(RADIUS),
      ),
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
    ),
    isDense: true,
  ),
  hint: Text('gender'),
  isExpanded: true,
  isDense: true,
  items: ['Male', 'Female'].map((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (_) {},
),


By default, dropdown menus have extra padding on both sides, making them wider than the button. You can achieve a consistent width with below approach:
Set ButtonThemeData.alignedDropdown to true in your button theme. This property specifically adjusts the dropdown menu width to match the button's width.
Here's an example:
ButtonTheme(
  alignedDropdown: true,
  child: DropdownButtonFormField( ... ),
)

Here's a full example as per your requirement:
ButtonTheme(
            alignedDropdown: true,
            child: DropdownButtonFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(16),
                  ),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(16),
                  ),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                ),
                isDense: true,
              ),
              hint: const Text('gender'),
              isExpanded: true,
              isDense: true,
              items: ['Male', 'Female'].map((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (_) {},
            ),
          )

Explanation:

When alignedDropdown is set to true, the button's existing start and end padding (typically 16px and 24px) is automatically applied to the dropdown menu. This ensures the content within the button and menu items aligns horizontally.

